# Creating Custom ISO Images

Tags: disk-image

I am working on creating some custom ISO images using primarily Fedora and CentOS. I want the image to be a bootable live CD with some specific files on it. I also want it to have the option to be able to be downloaded to the hard drive. I've read some various articles but want to get a few more opinions since I've never done this before. Currently I'm trying 2 different methods.

1. Install Fedora with the configuration exactly how I want it and then run the livecd-tools program to pull everything I currently have to an ISO. I haven't got this to work yet but I do see a few issues with it. Such as the default passwords I had to put in.
2. Run a Fedora live CD and install a few things I want on it and then copy the image of it. I believe this would work better since it has more of a live cd feel. However I"m not 100% sure how I should go about pulling the current image to my own ISO.

I know some people have said to use mkisofs and a few other programs but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can convert a complete folder, (and making its image boot-able) to an ISO file using **mkisofs** utility